# Override a CSS class?

Tags: html, css

I have added a css file inside `head` or `<h:head>` of template file like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/style.css" />
```

Now i want to override below class of this css(style.css) file for few pages

```
.body-main{ width:800px; float:left;display: inline-block;}
```

i have to use like this

```
 .body-main{ width:90%; float:left;display: inline-block;}
```

One way to create another file and use `!important` then it would work but i don't want to use `!important`, can someone suggest any other way to do.

I am using JSF/Facelet template approach to create pages

Comment: Make sure that the css that overrides is below the original and that it follows the same hierarchy structure. then you won't need !important

Comment: It should work without `!important` as long as the overriding rule is defined *after* the original and/or has more specificity in its selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution is give some id to the element which is having body-main class and 
write css using id selector it will override style.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked

Comment: @Allen: Many of these kinds of basic question have 'duplicates' in Stack Overflow. I understand that flagging as a duplicate does not give you reputation points, but it keeps Stack Overflow 'clean'. So please next time take that into consideration

Comment: @Kukeltje If you are saying its a trick to get more reputation than i suppose you also tried this trick to get reputation in your early days of Stackoverflow :)

Comment: No, not a real trick but new people often don't know the possibility to flag as a duplicate. And yes the incentive to find duplicates is (to) low so I do think people are inclined to just answer. Imo one should get 5 reputation if a one is the first to flag a duplicate and it is eventually acknowledged by others.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Most importantly, the rule for you here would be.

> In the case of specificity equality, the latest declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important core features of *Cascading Stylesheets* is the **Cascade**.

Thanks to the **Cascade**, later rules applied to an element will always overwrite earlier rules applied to the same element.

Consequently, if you write:

```
.body-main {width: 800px; float: left; display: inline-block;}

.body-main {width: 90%;}

.body-main {width: 80%;}

.body-main {width: 70%;}
```

then the element which has `class="body-main"` will have a width of `70%`.

It doesn't matter how many rules you declare for a given element in the **cascade** - the last rule in the cascade for that element is the one which will apply to that element.

Comment: So that rule i have to write in CSS file or jsp/jsf/html page? Second question will i have to create another css file to write this rule because for some pages i want to to use previous CSS class for new pages only i have to override css.

Answer (score -1):

As **@Allen** mentioned in his answer i tried that in the same CSS file i added css class like this

```
#body-main{ width:90%; float:left;display: inline-block;}
```

and previously i am using

```
<div class="body-main">
.....
.....
.....
</div>
```

Now i am using

```
<div id="body-main">
.....
.....
.....
</div>
```

Now it is working fine.

Comment: No need to 'answer' like this. If you think the info is relevant, propose an edit of the accepted answer. In fact the best answer here is the one about specificity! That is basic css knowledge that should be aquired. In there is also info about if an id or class selector is more specific.